# Should TF-IDF Score be Identical for Every Ngram with the Same Frequency in a Document

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am using `sklearn` to find frequencies and tf-idf scores for bigrams from a set of 50 documents. Let's say one of the cleaned documents is "run fast slow".

The output is:

```
ngram     freq    tfidf
run fast  1       .23
fast slow 1       .23
```

The ngrams in the output for that one document *are* found in other documents. Let's say "run fast" is found 20 times in the document collection and "fast slow" is found 30 times. Why are the tfidf scores the same for ngrams within a document that have the same frequency?

This doesn't intuitively seem like the correct output since the frequency across the document collection varies.

This is the code I am using to extract the features. It takes a grouped df and a text column from that df:

```
def extractFeatures(groupedDF, textCol):
    cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b", stop_words=None, ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
    tv = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b", stop_words=None, ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
    features = pd.DataFrame()
    for id, group in tqdm(groupedDF):
           freq = cv.fit_transform(group[textCol])
           tfidf = tv.fit_transform(group[textCol])
           freq = sum(freq).toarray()[0]
           tfidf.todense()
           tfidf = tfidf.toarray()[0]
           freq = pd.DataFrame(freq, columns=['frequency'])
           tfidf = pd.DataFrame(tfidf, columns=['tfidf'])
           dfinner = pd.DataFrame(cv.get_feature_names(), columns=['ngram'])
           dfinner['map'] = id
           dfinner = dfinner.join(freq)
           results = dfinner.join(tfidf)
           features = features.append(results)
    return features
```

Comment: I think this belongs on Cross Validated

Comment: it's possible - but since I'm not sure the output from `sklearn` is correct, I think it may also be a programming question.

Comment: Are you sure run fast occurs 20 times and fast slow is 30 times?

Comment: i don't know exact counts, but yes. in each of my real world documents, every ngram with the same frequency in a particular document has the same tfidf score.